# There is no Penrose process for light right?

Tags: black-holes, speed-of-light

As far as I know, Wikipedia says the following about the [Penrose Process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penrose_process):

> "During the Penrose process, a working body falls (thick black line in
> the figure) into the ergonomics area (grey area.) At the lowest point
> (red dot), the body fires an electrical discharge toward behind;
> however, to a distant observer, both seem to continue to move forward
> due to the frame's drag (albeit at different speeds).thin gray line)
> down the horizon event of the black hole (black disk) and the rest of
> the body, being accelerated, fly away (black thin stream) with excess
> energy (more than offset).The loss of ballistics and energy is used to
> shoot it)."

I replaced Wikipedia's "body" with a beam of light. Suppose: when the beam approaches the black hole's active range, it will split off a small amount of energy. That tiny amount of energy is sucked into the horizon by the black hole. its event while the rest of the beam exits the black hole. According to Wikipedia:

> "The rest of the body, accelerated, flies out of the black hole"

. But with light, they are always moving at a constant speed so how can they speed up. Penrose process doesn't apply to light or am I mistaken somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equivalent of the Penrose process for radiation (including) light is called superradiance.

Waves with a frequency below the horizon frequency, can actually gain energy by depositing negative energy into a rotating black hole. This amplification manifests as the scattered waves having a higher amplitude than the original ingoing wave.

This process is also reminiscent of the stimulated emission that happens in lasers.